# Launch automitically Python Script when an event occurs

Tags: python, events, outlook

I have a Python script that should control if an incoming email in Outlook is the one expected, with the expected attachment.

For example:
I'm waiting for an email from duffy@duck.com. when I receive an email, I check whether the sender is duffy@duck.com or not. If it is, I go on and check the attachment; otherwise I stop the read and wait the next email.

What I would like to have is not a continously running script, but an automatically launched script when the event "Outlook received an email" is catched.

I have no idea, how I could manage this situation. I hope everything is clear.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates in your question. This is to help for future visitors understand and to cause less confusion. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the following [example](http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/how-to-trigger-an-application-via-email-in-outlook-56870.html), you can see how to trigger an application via email in Outlook, using 'Rules and Alerts' option.

BTW, there's another [example](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

As Gal Dreiman suggested, the solution is:

Create Rules in Outlook with a Python Script. Launch it and rules will be permanent in Outlook, until the user delete. In this way the sender check is automatically and an other Python script might be launched.

Furthermore I share a [link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-March/010190.html) in which an example, about how to implement a rule in Outlook with Python, is shown.

**EDIT**

As written [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/specifying-rule-actions), it's **not possible** to create programmatically rules, to call and run scripts.

I can't find any workaround!